# Serve up PC hard drive as USB mass storage

Tags: windows, linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

Is there a software package available that can serve up a hard-drive internal to a PC and make it available over USB to other USB Master nodes as mass storage?

Ex: take your C: or /dev/hda drive on a PC (let's call the computer *PC-A*), and run a driver program which makes your C: or /dev/hda drive available to external devices as USB mass storage.  When you'd hook up another PC (*PC-B*) to PC-A via USB, it would detect a USB mass storage device, which is C: or /dev/hda on PC-A.

Is this even possible?

---

**EDIT:**  I know that there are other ways of making data on a drive available between two different computers (eg. putting PC-A's hdd in a USB-drive-enclosure, or having PC-A make the hdd available via a network share).  But **I'd like to know if the method that I describe above is even technically possible.**

Comment: It should be possible, the TouchBook basically does this. Maybe ask on the AlwaysInnovating forums: http://alwaysinnovating.com/forums/viewforum.php?f=8

Comment: See my answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/427092/how-to-turn-a-folder-into-usb-drive-mass-storage/427107#comment490470_427107

Comment: This may be related: https://superuser.com/questions/215466/make-nas-appear-as-a-usb-drive/1613829#1613829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If you use a normal cable, the hosts will both try to provide power over the usb cable causing a short with the end result ranging from fried usb ports to dead motherboards. You need to buy a special USB to USB transfer cable with a controller somewhere between the jacks.

Answer (score 1):

The two better ways to approach this would be:

1. Get an external enclosure for the hard drive (http://www.newegg.com)
2. Share the drive as a network drive for other machines to use