# Is there a way to make a pc look like a USB drive to a device that reads content from a USB drive?

Tags: usb

I have a device (for example, a music player or a TV) that has a USB port and will read files off a thumb drive and play or display them.  Is there a way connect that USB port to a PC and in software on the PC serve up files to a virtual drive that would then be recognized by the music player or TV as present in its USB port?

I assume that this would have to be a combination hardware and software for the reasons described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/41841/serve-up-pc-hard-drive-as-usb-mass-storage).

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a PC as a external drive via USB?](http://superuser.com/questions/228433/is-it-possible-to-use-a-pc-as-a-external-drive-via-usb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is something similar to a USB data copy cable. The problem is that data copy cables just use custom software on both ends to manage the copy - they don't actually make anything look like a drive. You need custom software on the PC end, and then enough brains in the middle to pretend to be a USB drive.

If you were up to reverse-engineering one of those copy cables, you might be able to use it as the basis for what you want, but you'd have to write all of the software yourself.