# Make SMB look like USB pendrive

Tags: usb, usb-storage, smb

I have a satellite decoder that lets me connect a USB device to it, allowing me to copy recordings off it.

Is there any way that I can somehow network this? What I suppose I am looking for is a USB gadget that makes an SMB share look like a USB pendrive.

I doubt it's possible, but thought I would ask!

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried and sounds a bit complicated, but you might want to try first a USB to Ethernet adapter:

> http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=589&name=10-100%20Ethernet%20USB

Or here there's the same issue:

> [Can I share a hard drive both over USB and SMB?](https://superuser.com/questions/41829/can-i-share-a-hard-drive-both-over-usb-and-smb)